# Lost value of variables

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

After start a detach Thread, the thread go to sleep for a while. At the End of the sleep time, a variable was changed. But the variable only change the value in the thread. After exit of the thread the change don't exist any more.

That code run under Lam/MPI 7.4. Don't now if that is different to normal gcc.

```
typedef struct theadSleep {
    struct task *task;
    int sleeptime;
    int result;
} ThreadSleep;

void sleepTask(void *dummy) {
    static volatile ThreadSleep *tS;
    tS = (ThreadSleep*) dummy;
    time_t t1;
    t1 = time(NULL );
    int t1int = (int) t1;
    t1int = t1int + tS->sleeptime;
    while (t1int >= (int) time(NULL )) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    tS->task->result = tS->result;
    pthread_exit(NULL );
}


// Function to start the thread
pthread_attr_t attrSleep; /* Attribut für Posix Thread */
pthread_t sleepT; /* Posix Thread */
static volatile ThreadSleep ts1;
ts1.result = 0;
ts1.sleeptime = 0;
ts1.result = resultRecieved[0];
ts1.sleeptime = resultRecieved[1];
ts1.task = tmpTask;
pthread_attr_init(&attrSleep);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrSleep, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
if (pthread_create(&sleepT, &attrSleep, &sleepTask, (void*) &ts1)   == -1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Fehler bei Starten des Sleep Threads Task %i Kind %i.\n",
  tmpTask->taskindex, tmpTask->taskkind);
}

        }
```

Here the staement `tS->task->result = tS->result;` has no effect!

Example, but error free.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct task {
        int result;
        int sleeptime;
} Task;

typedef struct theadSleep {
        struct task *task;
        int sleeptime;
        int result;
} ThreadSleep;


void sleepTask(void *dummy) {
    ThreadSleep *tS;
    tS = (ThreadSleep*) dummy;
    time_t t1;

    t1 = time(NULL );
    int t1int = (int) t1;
    t1int = t1int + tS->sleeptime;
    while (t1int >= (int) time(NULL )) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    tS->task->result = tS->result;
    printf("Detach Thread is ready.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL );
}

int main (){
  Task *newtask = malloc(sizeof(Task));
  newtask->result = 0;
  newtask->sleeptime = 3;

  pthread_attr_t attrSleep; /* Attribut für Posix Thread */
  pthread_t sleepT; /* Posix Thread */
  ThreadSleep ts1;
  ts1.result = 14;
  ts1.sleeptime = newtask->sleeptime;
  ts1.task = newtask;

  pthread_attr_init(&attrSleep);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrSleep, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
  if (pthread_create(&sleepT, &attrSleep, &sleepTask, (void*) &ts1)
                                        == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fehler bei Starten des Sleep Threads.\n");
  }
  sleep (5);

  printf("Task result: %i \n",newtask->result);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give us a [short, self contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that clearly shows the problem.

Comment: Did just finish the code example. But that one is error free. The code example you see here, is in different source files. And it is compiled with mpicc from LAM/MPI. The self contained example is compiled with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5).

Comment: I'm not sure what value the example that doesn't exhibit the error has to your question.

Comment: The value for me is, I try to find the error and pilcrow want a short example. I gave the best I can do. But that one I wrote, is error free. On the other hand, work in a detach posix thread and change a value is nothing new. If that fail under LAM/MPI somebody now that.

Answer (score 1):

You have no [memory synchronization](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_10) between the "sleepTask" thread and the main thread.

So, the sleepTask thread may update some area of memory (like `tS->task->result`), but the main thread is *not* guaranteed to see this update.  (It will eventually, but eventually can be a long time in concurrent programming.)

Mutex-protected access would solve this problem, as would having the main thread join the worker thread and then checking the memory in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `memcpy(tS, dummy, sizeof(ThreadSleep));`
Also, remove `tS = (ThreadSleep*) dummy;`
That applies if you want to make changes locally only. Else, forget the memcpy and malloc. In that case, just cast the 'dummy' to ThreadSleep*. Buit, if you leave it and if you want to avoid memory leaks, also add `free();`.

Comment: I try to change my code. You see the differences in my example. But that dosn't help.

Comment: I don't understand what behavior you have and what do you expect to get? If you are about to answer this one, please use debugger and provide some useful information (values). Otherwise this question is a nice candidate for deletion.

Comment: My English is not the best, because of that my problem is not good explained. I use  a test licence from DDT [link](http://www.allinea.com/products/ddt/) and with that, I saw that the variable 'tS->task->result' change, after thread exit it change again to the original value. I need a function, that change value after a specified time. Without block the whole program. If I try the same thing with gcc, nothing went wrong.